# ShellScript parsing a sting variable to notify-send

Tags: string, bash, sh, notify-send

I have never seen this anywhere in my search
I am making a script to see if I can send a string variable to notify-send
so far

```
$MESSAGE='Hello world!'
notify-send "`$MESSAGE`" -t 1
```

will trow

```
Hello command not found
```

and

```
notify-send $MESSAGE -t 1
```

sends a too many argument error

so is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MESSAGE='Hello world!'
notify-send "$MESSAGE" -t 1
```

We declare a variable using `NAME=VALUE` in bash. There's no `$` sign before the variable name. Then you enclose variable value obtained by using `$` character using `"`. The `` ` `` character is used as a command substitution, same as `$(...)`.When you write `` "`$MESSAGE`" ``, you tell you bash to execute command named `Hello` with argument `world!`. As such command does not exists, your bash returns `Hello command not found`.